# How can I draw a line in a-frame?

Tags: line, aframe

I'm trying to plot a line with this script:

```
var gScene = document.querySelector("a-scene");
var p2=document.createElement('a-entity');
p2.setAttribute('geometry',{primitive: 'line', start: "0 0 0", end: "10 0 0"});
p2.setAttribute('color', '#aaf');
gScene.appendChild(p2);
```

but i get this error and I don't know why:

```
core:a-node:error Failure loading node:   Error: Unknown geometry schema `line`
    at i.updateSchema (geometry.js:79:26)
    at initComponent (component.js:311:35)
    at i.updateProperties (component.js:302:12)
    at HTMLElement.value (a-entity.js:490:19)
    at HTMLElement.value (a-entity.js:463:14)
    at a-entity.js:249:14
    at a-node.js:127:21
```

Can someone help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless defined as a custom geometry, `line` is not a [built-in geometry](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/geometry.html#built-in-geometries) - there is a [line](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/line.html#sidebar) component which you can use to draw a straight line:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>

<a-scene>
  <a-entity line="start: -2 1.6 -2; end: 2 0 -2; color: red" 
            line__2="start: 2 1.6 -2; end: -2 0 -2; color: green"></a-entity>
  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

---

If you want multiple points, then you can create a component which will create a `THREE.Line` consisting of multiple points:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("some-line", {
    init: function() {
      // create an array of points. 
      const points = [];
      points.push(new THREE.Vector3(-1.25, -0.35, 0));
      points.push(new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0.15, 0));
      points.push(new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, 0.25, 0));
      points.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0));
      points.push(new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0.25, 0));
      points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0.15, 0));
      points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1.25, -0.35, 0));

      // create the line material
      const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0x0000ff});
      // create the geometry from points
      const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);
      // create a THREE.Line from the geometry and material
      const line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
      // add it to this entity
      this.el.object3D.add(line);
    }
  })
</script>
<a-scene>
  <a-entity position="0 1.6 -2" some-line></a-entity>
  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

---

Dynamically added from js:

```js
const scene = document.querySelector("a-scene");
// when the scene is loaded
scene.addEventListener("loaded", () => {
  // create an entity
  const el = document.createElement("a-entity");
  // append it to the scene
  scene.appendChild(el);
  // set the position and line component
  el.setAttribute("position", "0 1.6 -2")
  el.setAttribute("some-line", "")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("some-line", {
    init: function() {
      // create an array of points. 
      const points = [];
      points.push(new THREE.Vector3(-1.25, -0.35, 0));
      points.push(new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0.15, 0));
      points.push(new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, 0.25, 0));
      points.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0));
      points.push(new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0.25, 0));
      points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0.15, 0));
      points.push(new THREE.Vector3(1.25, -0.35, 0));

      // create the line material
      const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0x0000ff});
      // create the geometry from points
      const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);
      // create a THREE.Line from the geometry and material
      const line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
      // add it to this entity
      this.el.object3D.add(line);
    }
  })
</script>
<a-scene>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. But I need to use javascript code. I have just try your code but I call it with javascript, like this:

var p=document.createElement('a-entity');
    p.setAttribute('geometry',{primitive: 'some-line', position: "0 1 2"});
    p.setAttribute('color', '#aaf');
    gScene.appendChild(p);

and I get the same error. 

I only need to plot a line (only one) but defined for 2 points (and in javascript code)

Thanks

Comment: @zorro68 It's not a primitive, I've updated my answer with another example

Comment: Sorry I did not see your updated. Im going to try it now